# Jaybird JDBC 3.0 - Connection Timing Out

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion, firebird, jaybird, firebird-3.0

I'm connecting to a Firebird 3.0 database using the Jaybird JDBC 3.0.3 driver. I'm connecting from within the ColdFusion Administrator -> Data Sources area. In the past, using JDBC 2.0 driver I created my data source as follows.

```
JDBC URL: jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:DATABASE_FILE_NAME
Driver Class: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
Username: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
```

However, this is not working now. I do not see anything obvious that I'm missing. I just get the error

> Timed out trying to establish connection

I did read that Jaybird 3.0 does not support Wire Encryption - so I need to set it to Enabled (not Required which is the default). I have already done this in the firebird.conf file and restarted the Firebird service.

Comment: Although you already fixed the issue, could you also post the full exception stacktrace from the logs? This might make it easier for people running into the same problem to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to download and use the Jaybird driver for JDK 1.7 rather than 1.8.  After I did that and restarted ColdFusion everything worked.

Comment: What JDK are you using for ColdFusion? It can be useful to get everything up to the current JVM

Comment: @JamesAMohler not sure honestly, I don't manage the server.  How would I check?

Comment: You can run `<cfdump var="#server#">`